# Typescript Promise.all for Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary, hashmap

I want to do the following demonstrated with an `Array` with a `Map`:

```
export class Example {

    // No errors
    public withArray(): Promise<Item[]> {
        var promises: Promise<Item>[] = [];
        promises.push(Promise.resolve(Item));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }

    // Issues with initialisation 
    public withMap(): Promise<Map<Item, Item>> {
        var promises: Promise<Map<Item, Item>> = new Map();
        promises.push(Promise.resolve([Item, Item]));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}
```

It complains with the following error message:

```
Type 'Map<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<Map<Item, Item>>': then, catch, finally
```

My question would be, how do I define the type `Map` on the `promises` so that I can add `[Key, Value]` to a Map that will then get returned.

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: "I'm quite sure the issue is in this line" well yes. It is explicitly stated in error message. You can't assign Map to variable that is expected to be an Array of Promises.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize it with a Map?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear then. How do I define the type `Promise<Map>` for my `var promises`. @captain-yossarian I'll quickly work on a fully reproducible example my bad. Will be lot of code tho for all the loops. Thought it would be clear that I just initialised the Map wrong.

Comment: I mean, `promises` is an **Array** of `Promise<...>`. Whatever is inside angle brackets doesn't matter to the initialization of the **array**. It's when you push promises into it that it matters.

Comment: Updated the question with fully reproducible example and more clear question.

Comment: The first code block is wrong: `Promise.all(promises);` will only run with an empty array. EDIT: after the edit, that's not the case.

Comment: So, what exactly should you have in the second case with the map? A promise that resolves to a map (that's what the code currently says) is wrong but so is `promises.push(item)` because a map doesn't have a push method. Is it supposed to be `Map<Item, Promise<Item>>`? Not sure how much it makes sense if the index (which should come from a promise) is also what is going to index itself. `Map<Promise<Item>, Promise<Item>>` makes more sense type-wise but not sure if it does more logical sense.

Comment: If you want the type `Promise<Map<TKey, TValue>>`, you should probably rename the variable from `promises` to `promise`, because you have only one promise that includes a map. You shouldn't push anything into it, you'll assign `Resolve(new Map(...))` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `var promises = Map<Item, Promise<Item>> = new Map()`.

An alternative way to write `Promise<Item>[]` would be `Array<Promise<Item>>`.
Notice that both cases indicate the same: an `Array` of `Promise`s that should resolve with `Item`. **Array** -> **promises** -> items.

In your second case, you are typing `Promise<Map<Item, Item>>`, which is a **Promise** -> **Map** -> items, instead of **Map** -> **promises** -> items. What you are looking for is a `Map<Item, Promise<Item>>`.

Also, there seem to be quite a few other issues with that code. Notice that `Map` does not have a `push` method.